# change output path for gcda files

Tags: c++, unit-testing, compilation, code-coverage

On my host machine I'm cross-compiling my cpp project for a specific target.
I use `--coverage` compiler flag in order to generate the .gcno and the .gcda files so that I can generate at the end the code coverage report for my project.

what I understood so far..

> **.gcno generated during compilation:**  The .gcno files, also known as "Notes Files", store metadata about the program's structure, such
> as function and branch information. They do not contain actual execution count data but provide the framework to map execution counts to specific code locations. This file is used during the coverage analysis phase to understand the structure of your code and identify which branches, lines, and functions are instrumented for coverage tracking and are not needed to generate the .gcda files.
>
> **.gcda generated during execution:** The .gcda files, also known as "Data Files", are updated during execution of the instrumented
> application to store the actual execution counts for different parts
> of the code. This information includes the number of times each branch
> is taken, each line is executed, and each function is called.

This means I dont need .gcno files on my target during execution, right?

**Problem/Question:**

During compilation the .gcno files are generated next to the object files to a folder like:

```
<path to workspace>/CMakeFiles/<binary name>-static_for_unit_tests.dir/src/foo.cpp.gcno
<path to workspace>/CMakeFiles/<binary name>-static_for_unit_tests.dir/src/foo.cpp.o
```

Now I move the compiled binary to my target and execute the application.
During execution I get errors like this:

```
profiling:<path to workspace>:Cannot create directory
profiling:<path to workspace>/CMakeFiles/<binary name>-static_for_unit_tests.dir/src/foo.cpp.gcda:Skip
```

Setting environment variables GCOV_PREFIX_STRIP and GCOV_PREFIX has no effect because I think the path is static.I only have access to one folder on my target, how can I change the output directory for the .gcno files?